# How to sum multiple value of array..?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have an array like this the sructure of my array, i need to sum "weight" value and push them to the end of array list with key "total_weight":

```
      {
  "730": [{
        "qty": "1",
        "product_id": 8,
        "product_name": "NIKE As M Dry Tee Legend 2.0 - Black\/Black\/Matte Silver [XL]",
        "product_price": 299000,
        "product_image": "1604906748nike-as-m-dry-tee-legend-20-blackblackmatte-silver-xl.jpg",
        "product_slug": "nike-as-m-dry-tee-legend-20-blackblackmatte-silver-xl",
        "weight": 100,
        "seller_origin": 730
    },
    {
        "qty": "1",
        "product_id": 7,
        "product_name": "Skipping jump rope Tali Skiping Loncat Speeds Anti Slip  100676 LX",
        "product_price": 25000,
        "product_image": "1604907088skipping-jump-rope-tali-skiping-loncat-speeds-anti-slip-100676-lx.jpg",
        "product_slug": "skipping-jump-rope-tali-skiping-loncat-speeds-anti-slip-lx-1006",
        "weight": 200,
        "seller_origin": 730
    },
    {
        "qty": 2,
        "product_id": 6,
        "product_name": "Kappa Track Suit Jacket - Black Black L",
        "product_price": 230000,
        "product_image": "1602820947kappa-track-suit-jacket-black-black-l.jpg",
        "product_slug": "kappa-track-suit-jacket-black-black-l",
        "weight": 100,
        "seller_origin": 730
    }
  ],
  "3641": [{
    "qty": "1",
    "product_id": 4,
    "product_name": "Groot Figure Guardian Pot Marvel",
    "product_price": 46999,
    "product_image": "1606719651groot-figure-guardian-pot-marvel.jpg",
    "product_slug": "groot-figure-guardian-pot-marvel",
    "weight": 300,
    "seller_origin": 3641
    }]
  }
```

i want generate summary of "weight" group by key of array like this:

```
{
  "730": [{
        "qty": "1",
        "product_id": 8,
        "product_name": "NIKE As M Dry Tee Legend 2.0 - Black\/Black\/Matte Silver [XL]",
        "product_price": 299000,
        "product_image": "1604906748nike-as-m-dry-tee-legend-20-blackblackmatte-silver-xl.jpg",
        "product_slug": "nike-as-m-dry-tee-legend-20-blackblackmatte-silver-xl",
        "weight": 100,
        "seller_origin": 730
    },
    {
        "qty": "1",
        "product_id": 7,
        "product_name": "Skipping jump rope Tali Skiping Loncat Speeds Anti Slip  100676 LX",
        "product_price": 25000,
        "product_image": "1604907088skipping-jump-rope-tali-skiping-loncat-speeds-anti-slip-100676-lx.jpg",
        "product_slug": "skipping-jump-rope-tali-skiping-loncat-speeds-anti-slip-lx-1006",
        "weight": 200,
        "seller_origin": 730
    },
    {
        "qty": 2,
        "product_id": 6,
        "product_name": "Kappa Track Suit Jacket - Black Black L",
        "product_price": 230000,
        "product_image": "1602820947kappa-track-suit-jacket-black-black-l.jpg",
        "product_slug": "kappa-track-suit-jacket-black-black-l",
        "weight": 100,
        "seller_origin": 730
    },
    "total_weight":400
  ],
  "3641": [{
    "qty": "1",
    "product_id": 4,
    "product_name": "Groot Figure Guardian Pot Marvel",
    "product_price": 46999,
    "product_image": "1606719651groot-figure-guardian-pot-marvel.jpg",
    "product_slug": "groot-figure-guardian-pot-marvel",
    "weight": 300,
    "seller_origin": 3641
    },
     "total_weight":300
      ]
  }
```

how to i get generate array like this by sum all of weight value of array?
i have try to sum of weight value and push them to the end of list array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with laravel collection `collect()` then you can use `->sum()` function

```php
foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
    $temp = collect($item);
    $data[$key]['total_weight'] = $temp->sum('weight');
}
return $data;
```

Comment: this is easy way to print all of array and get "total_weight"

Answer (score 3):

Supporse you array is named $data

```
    foreach($data as &$array){
        $array["total_weight"] = array_sum(array_column($array,"weight"));
    }
```

Comment: +1, but might be helpful to include the conversion to a native array, as this will fail on what OP describes as their 'array' (which is literally a JSON string).